# Scalability issues in using Pushing notifications as the only means of delivering messages in a messaging app

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, google-cloud-messaging, apns-php

I am designing a Mobile Messenger(which will work on Android/Windows/iOS).I am not designing it just for learning purposes so my app needs to be as real-time as possible while serving millions of clients.

### Current Architecture

Right now,I have employed push notifications as the only means of delivering notifications to the clients.The logic for sending notifications is something like there is one queue which collects all the messages and then a cron job processes that queue and send messages to the clients one by one.All is well right now,but what if my app has to send millions of messages (residing in the queue)?
Should I employ some alternate ways to deliver notifications?Also,is there any kind of quota for push notifications on iOS or Android.I only know about WNS(Windows Notification Service).

If you had to suggest an alternate way of delivering notifications for such an app,what would it be?
Thanks for having a look at my problem.